# How to plot Month name in correct order, using strftime?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Here's a quick peek of my dataframe:

```
   local_date  amount
0  2017-08-16   10.00
1  2017-10-26   21.70
2  2017-11-04    5.00
3  2017-11-12   37.20
4  2017-11-13   10.00
5  2017-11-18   31.00
6  2017-11-27   14.00
7  2017-11-29   10.00
8  2017-11-30   37.20
9  2017-12-16    8.00
10 2017-12-17   43.20
11 2017-12-17   49.60
12 2017-12-19  102.50
13 2017-12-19   28.80
14 2017-12-22   72.55
15 2017-12-23   24.80
16 2017-12-24   62.00
17 2017-12-26   12.40
18 2017-12-26   15.50
19 2017-12-26   40.00
20 2017-12-28   57.60
21 2017-12-31   37.20
22 2018-01-01   18.60
23 2018-01-02   12.40
24 2018-01-04   32.40
25 2018-01-05   17.00
26 2018-01-06   28.80
27 2018-01-11   20.80
28 2018-01-12   10.00
29 2018-01-12   26.00
```

I am trying to plot monthly sum of transactions, which is fine, except for ugly x-ticks:
[image]

I would like to change it to Name of the month and year (e.g. Jan 2019). So I sort the dates, change them using `strftime` and plot it again, but the order of the date are completely messed up.

The code I used to sort the dates and conver them is:

```
transactions = transactions.sort_values(by='local_date')

transactions['month_year'] = transactions['local_date'].dt.strftime('%B %Y')

#And then groupby that column:

transactions.groupby('month_year').amount.sum().plot(kind='bar')
```

When doing this, the `Month_year` are paired together. January 2019 comes after January 2018 etc. etc.

I thought sorting by date would fix this, but it doesn't. What's the best way to approach this? 
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert column to mont periods by [`Series.dt.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html) and then change `PeriodIndex` to custom format in `rename`:

```
transactions = transactions.sort_values(by='local_date')
(transactions.groupby(transactions['local_date'].dt.to_period('m'))
             .amount.sum()
             .rename(lambda x: x.strftime('%B %Y'))
             .plot(kind='bar'))
```

Alternative solution:

```
transactions = transactions.sort_values(by='local_date')
s = transactions.groupby(transactions['local_date'].dt.to_period('m')).amount.sum()
s.index = s.index.strftime('%B %Y')
s.plot(kind='bar')
```

[image: g]